# extract substring from a long string in R

Tags: r, string, substring, extract

I have a string that looks like this :

```
C|3_prime_UTR_variant|MODIFIER|SRY|ENSG00000184895|Transcript|ENST00000383070|protein_coding|1/1||ENST00000383070.1:c.*51C>G||762|||||rs781744002|1||-1||SNV|1|HGNC|11311|YES|||CCDS14772.1|ENSP00000372547|Q05066|Q6J4J1&A7WPU8|UPI0000135F78|1||||||C:0||||||||C:0|C:2.855e-05|C:0|C:3.067e-05|C:0|C:0|C:5.473e-05|C:0||||||||||||,C|upstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|RNASEH2CP1|ENSG00000237659|Transcript|ENST00000454281|processed_pseudogene||||||||||rs781744002|1|2889|1||SNV|1|HGNC|24117|YES||||||||||||||C:0||||||||C:0|C:2.855e-05|C:0|C:3.067e-05|C:0|C:0|C:5.473e-05|C:0||||||||||||,C|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|RNU6-1334P|ENSG00000251841|Transcript|ENST00000516032|snRNA||||||||||rs781744002|1|2085|1||SNV|1|HGNC|48297|YES||||||||||||||C:0||||||||C:0|C:2.855e-05|C:0|C:3.067e-05|C:0|C:0|C:5.473e-05|C:0||||||||||||,C|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|SRY|ENSG00000184895|Transcript|ENST00000525526|protein_coding||||||||||rs781744002|1|70|-1||SNV|1|HGNC|11311|||||ENSP00000437575||F5H6J8|UPI0002064E1A|1||||||C:0||||||||C:0|C:2.855e-05|C:0|C:3.067e-05|C:0|C:0|C:5.473e-05|C:0||||||||||||,C|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|SRY|ENSG00000184895|Transcript|ENST00000534739|protein_coding||||||||||rs781744002|1|166|-1||SNV|1|HGNC|11311|||||ENSP00000438917||F5H3H1|UPI0002064E1B|1||||||C:0||||||||C:0|C:2.855e-05|C:0|C:3.067e-05|C:0|C:0|C:5.473e-05|C:0||||||||||||"
```

what I wish to do is to extract from the string the data that is bold

C|***3_prime_UTR_variant***|MODIFIER|***SRY***|ENSG00000184895|Transcript|ENST00000383070|protein_coding|1/1||ENST00000383070.1:c.*51C>G||762|||||rs781744002|1||-1||SNV|1|HGNC|11311|YES|||CCDS14772.1|ENSP00000372547|Q05066|Q6J4J1&A7WPU8|UPI0000135F78|1||||||C:0||||||||C:0|C:2.855e-05|C:0|C:3.067e-05|C:0|C:0|C:5.473e-05|C:0||||||||||||,C|upstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|RNASEH2CP1|ENSG00000237659|Transcript|ENST00000454281|processed_pseudogene||||||||||rs781744002|1|2889|1||SNV|1|HGNC|***24117***|YES||||||||||||||C:0||||||||C:0|C:2.855e-05|C:0|C:3.067e-05|C:0|C:0|C:5.473e-05|C:0||||||||||||,C|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|RNU6-1334P|ENSG00000251841|Transcript|ENST00000516032|snRNA||||||||||rs781744002|1|2085|1||SNV|1|HGNC|48297|YES||||||||||||||C:0||||||||C:0|C:2.855e-05|C:0|C:3.067e-05|C:0|C:0|C:5.473e-05|C:0||||||||||||,C|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|SRY|ENSG00000184895|Transcript|ENST00000525526|protein_coding||||||||||rs781744002|1|70|-1||SNV|1|HGNC|11311|||||ENSP00000437575||F5H6J8|UPI0002064E1A|1||||||C:0||||||||C:0|C:2.855e-05|C:0|C:3.067e-05|C:0|C:0|C:5.473e-05|C:0||||||||||||,C|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|SRY|ENSG00000184895|Transcript|ENST00000534739|protein_coding||||||||||rs781744002|1|166|-1||SNV|1|HGNC|11311|||||ENSP00000438917||F5H3H1|UPI0002064E1B|1||||||C:0||||||||C:0|C:2.855e-05|C:0|C:3.067e-05|C:0|C:0|C:5.473e-05|C:0||||||||||||"

usually, i use this type of code:

```
str_extract(data_snp$vep, "(?<=xxx=)[^|]+")
```

but this time it didn't work. Is there any way that R can do this? thank you:)

Comment: Do you always want to extract the second (here `3_prime_UTR_variant`) and the fourth part (here: `SRY`)? Is `MODIFIER` always on third place? We need more information about the structure of your vector.

Comment: @MartinGal i always want to extract the second (here 3_prime_UTR_variant)   and MODIFIER isnt always third but the (SRY) or any other value comes always fourth and 24117 comes always after HGNC the goal is to extract them to different column

Comment: ?? "strong black color", is that supposed to mean "bold"? (When somebody has chosen a high-contrast or dark theme, the font may be white on a dark background, not black.)

Comment: `lapply(strsplit(you_string, "|", fixed=T), "[", c(2,4,x))`. Replace X by the position of 24117 in the vector(x=93 thanks the r2evans post).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `read.delim` for this:

```r
txt <- "C|3_prime_UTR_variant|MODIFIER|SRY|ENSG00000184895|Transcript|ENST00000383070|protein_coding|1/1||ENST00000383070.1:c.*51C>G||762|||||rs781744002|1||-1||SNV|1|HGNC|11311|YES|||CCDS14772.1|ENSP00000372547|Q05066|Q6J4J1&A7WPU8|UPI0000135F78|1||||||C:0||||||||C:0|C:2.855e-05|C:0|C:3.067e-05|C:0|C:0|C:5.473e-05|C:0||||||||||||,C|upstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|RNASEH2CP1|ENSG00000237659|Transcript|ENST00000454281|processed_pseudogene||||||||||rs781744002|1|2889|1||SNV|1|HGNC|24117|YES||||||||||||||C:0||||||||C:0|C:2.855e-05|C:0|C:3.067e-05|C:0|C:0|C:5.473e-05|C:0||||||||||||,C|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|RNU6-1334P|ENSG00000251841|Transcript|ENST00000516032|snRNA||||||||||rs781744002|1|2085|1||SNV|1|HGNC|48297|YES||||||||||||||C:0||||||||C:0|C:2.855e-05|C:0|C:3.067e-05|C:0|C:0|C:5.473e-05|C:0||||||||||||,C|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|SRY|ENSG00000184895|Transcript|ENST00000525526|protein_coding||||||||||rs781744002|1|70|-1||SNV|1|HGNC|11311|||||ENSP00000437575||F5H6J8|UPI0002064E1A|1||||||C:0||||||||C:0|C:2.855e-05|C:0|C:3.067e-05|C:0|C:0|C:5.473e-05|C:0||||||||||||,C|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|SRY|ENSG00000184895|Transcript|ENST00000534739|protein_coding||||||||||rs781744002|1|166|-1||SNV|1|HGNC|11311|||||ENSP00000438917||F5H3H1|UPI0002064E1B|1||||||C:0||||||||C:0|C:2.855e-05|C:0|C:3.067e-05|C:0|C:0|C:5.473e-05|C:0||||||||||||"
unlist(read.delim(text = txt, sep = "|", header = FALSE)[,c(2,4,93)], use.names = FALSE)
# [1] "3_prime_UTR_variant" "SRY"                 "24117"
```

If you use `unlist(.)` without `use.names=FALSE`, you get `V1` etc for names, but they are harmless.

Comment: is it possible to get an output without the       V2                    V4                   V93  for example ("3_prime_UTR_variant","SPR","24117")? thank you for the help :)

Comment: You asked for strings, so what I provided gave you that. The names are completely harmless and can be ignored. See my edit. In place of `unlist(..., use.names=FALSE)`, we could also have done `unname(unlist(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to solve your problem:

```
lapply(strsplit(data_snp$vep, "\\|+"), \(x) intersect(x, c("3_prime_UTR_variant", "SRY", "24117")))

[[1]]
[1] "3_prime_UTR_variant" "SRY"                 "24117"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strsplit()`:

```r
strsplit(txt, '\\|')[[1]][c(2, 4, 93)]

# [1] "3_prime_UTR_variant" "SRY"                 "24117"
```

or `stringr::word()`:

```r
stringr::word(txt, c(2, 4, 93), sep = '\\|')

# [1] "3_prime_UTR_variant" "SRY"                 "24117"
```